# Trying to calculate a date of birth

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 300 people in it and need to calculate their ages as of 04/01/2017 based on their DOBs. I know I am missing populating my @dob variable and can't figure it out. Here is what I have:

```
Declare @dob  datetime

Declare @cutoff datetime

set @cutoff = '2017-04-01'

Select dob, FLOOR((CAST (@cutoff AS INTEGER) - CAST(@dob AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) AS Age,   
 FROM  [PGADCP].[dcp].[person] p
```

Comment: How about using the DateDiff function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?

Comment: Be aware that not all years have the same number of days. Calculating with 365.25 is hence only an approximation. You may face situations where you calculate one year too few.

Comment: @vmd1310 What's wrong with `DATEDIFF`?  Why do you want to create your own arithmetic?

Answer (score 1):

This is complicated in SQL Server.  What you need to do is *subtract three months and one day* and use `datediff()` as of '2016-12-31'.

That is:

```
select p.dob,
       datediff(year, dateadd(month, -3, dob), '2016-12-31') as AgeAtCutoff
```

The reason is that `datediff()` counts year boundaries.  Presumably, you don't want to add a year of age to someone born in December.

Another approach is the approximate approach:

```
select datediff(day, dob, '2017-04-01') / 365.25
```

This works pretty well for most things.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to compute the number of full years manually, use [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) function with `year` parameter:

```
SELECT
    p.dob
,   DATEDIFF(year, p.dob, @cutoff) AS AgeAsOfCutoff  
FROM  [PGADCP].[dcp].[person] p
```

Note that you do not need `@dob` variable at all, because the value of `dob` comes from the corresponding column in `[person]` table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method to calculate the age:

```
DECLARE @cutoff datetime = '20170401';
SELECT 
    (CAST(CONVERT(char(8), @cutoff, 112) AS int) -
    CAST(CONVERT(char(8), dob, 112) AS int)) /10000 AS Age
FROM [PGADCP].[dcp].[person];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you their exact age from the cut-off

```
declare @asat date = '2017-01-01'

SELECT   (DATEDIFF(HOUR, date_of_birth, @asat) / 8766) AS [Age] 
from myPeople
```

Test

```
declare @asat date = '2017-11-17'
declare @mydbo date = '1981-11-18'

SELECT   (DATEDIFF(HOUR, @mydbo, @asat) / 8766) AS [Age]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's simple math. Subtract the birth year from the year 2017. Then check whether birth month/day is before 01/04, because in this case you must subtract a year, as that year's birthday was not reached yet.

```
select 
  dob, 
  2017 - year(dob) - case when '01/04' > convert(char(5), dob, 1) then 1 else 0 end as age
from pgadcp.dcp.person;
```